# How to fix unexpected token ';' error on an expo project?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

When I started my react-native android app using expo via QR code, I received this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNIE1.jpg

What was weird was that the error did not appear on my expo console, but it only appeared on my phone. I looked into the hashAssetFiles.js and this was the code.

```
'use strict';

const md5File = require('md5-file/promise');

module.exports = function hashAssetFiles(asset) {
  return Promise.all(asset.files.map(md5File)).then(hashes => {
    asset.fileHashes = hashes;
    return asset;
  });
};
```

Comment: Could be the way you're importing that lib. With React Native you should use `import md5File from 'md5-file/promise'`

Comment: According to ES6, we don't need to use comma(;) at the end of the function, that's might be the issue.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. To make sure, which ; do you mean specifically?